# How can I consolidate several Perl one-liners into a single script?

Tags: string, perl, substitution

I would like to move several one liners into a single script.

For example:

```
perl -i.bak -pE "s/String_ABC/String_XYZ/g" Cities.Txt
perl -i.bak -pE "s/Manhattan/New_England/g" Cities.Txt
```

Above works well for me but at the expense of two disk I/O operations.

I would like to move the aforementioned logic into a single script so that all substitutions are effectuated with the file opened and edited only once.

EDIT1: Based on your recommendations, I wrote this snippet in a script which when invoked from a windows batch file simply hangs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak -p Cities.Txt
use strict;
use warnings;

while( <> ){
s/String_ABC/String_XYZ/g;
s/Manhattan/New_England/g;
print;
}
```

EDIT2: OK, so here is how I implemented your recommendation. Works like a charm!

**Batch file**:

```
perl -i.bal MyScript.pl Cities.Txt
```

**MyScript.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while( <> ){
s/String_ABC/String_XYZ/g;
s/Manhattan/New_England/g;
print;
}
```

Thanks a lot to everyone that contributed.

Comment: You do realize that you can use a single one-liner, right?  `perl -i.bak -pE "s/String_ABC/String_XYZ/g;s/Manhattan/New_England/g" Cities.Txt`

Comment: Yes, but I have 60+ substitutions to perform and passing them via a command line is not tenable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-p` wraps the argument to `-E` with:

```
while( <> ) {
    # argument to -E
    print;
    }
```

So, take all the arguments to `-E` and put them in the `while`:

```
while( <> ) {
    s/String_ABC/String_XYZ/g;
    s/Manhattan/New_England/g;
    print;
    }
```

The `-i` sets the `$^I` variable, which turns on some special magic handling `ARGV`:

```
$^I = "bak";
```

The `-E` turns on the new features for that versions of Perl. You can do that by just specifying the version:

```
use v5.10;
```

However, you don't use anything loaded with that, at least in what you've shown us.

If you want to see everything a one-liner does, put a [`-MO=Deparse`](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse) in there:

```
% perl -MO=Deparse -i.bak -pE "s/Manhattan/New_England/g" Cities.Txt
BEGIN { $^I = ".bak"; }
BEGIN {
    $^H{'feature_unicode'} = q(1);
    $^H{'feature_say'} = q(1);
    $^H{'feature_state'} = q(1);
    $^H{'feature_switch'} = q(1);
}
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/Manhattan/New_England/g;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put arguments on the #! line.  Perl will read them, even on Windows.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak -p

s/String_ABC/String_XYZ/g;
s/Manhattan/New_England/g;
```

or you can keep it a one-liner as @ephemient said in the comments.

```
perl -i.bak -pE "s/String_ABC/String_XYZ/g; s/Manhattan/New_England/g" Cities.Txt
```

`-i` + `-p` basically puts a while loop around your program.  Each line comes in as `$_`, your code runs, and `$_` is printed out at the end.  Repeat.  So you can have as many statements as you want.

Comment: Well, the -p adds the while loop and a print statement. The -i doesn't  have anything to do with that, but it does set $^I.

Comment: Multiple arguments in the shebang line is not portable... although my Perl binary surprises me by dealing with that alright.  When did that start happening?

Comment: @ephemient I've never heard of a problem with putting switches on the #! line, been doing it for a long time.  Got a citation?  Perl pulls switches out of #! itself, has for a long long time, so what the OS does is probably moot.

Comment: it might be when you have #!/usr/bin/env perl <args>. On linux, that attempts to execute a program called "perl <args>". On any other unix variant, it executes perl with the specified args.

Comment: When you have `#!/usr/bin/perl -i.bak -p` in `./script.pl`, Linux will run `'/usr/bin/perl' '-i.bak -p' './script.pl'` (perfectly acceptable behavior under POSIX).  I'm surprised, but a bit of experimentation shows that Perl 5.10.1 on Linux will re-split its arguments on spaces...