# Can Perl one-liners be used in Perl script?

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and I was using Perl one-liners along with few simple Perl scripts for my task.

I would like to know if its possible to combine bunch of one-liners in code format and run just that particular file containing the one-liners? For example, if I have 3 one-liners which are to be run one by one, can I put these 3 one-liners in a single file named *file.pl* and run that?

```
oneliner....
oneliner....

code

oneliner....
```

The required format of what I am interested in is showed above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want a shell script in which you just have the one liners:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 perl -le '...'
 perl -ane '...'
 perl -e '...'
```

If you want to run a one-liner in the middle of a Perl program, you could do it with [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

system( q( perl -le '...' ) );
```

However, if you are already in a Perl program, you can just expand the one-liner to it's non-shorthand code and put it in the program. See, for instance, [How can I consolidate several Perl one-liners into a single script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858147/consolidating-several-perl-one-liners-into-a-script/11858528#11858528)

Comment: I am not sure if i am supposed ask this here in this comment. But I am badly in need of the solution for my previous question about "compare files and storing similar data into different files" even though it has been answered I am not sure why those solution dont work for me. Can i expect your help for that question. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @unkaitha Hmmmm... question asked for a a script called 'file.pl', i.e. a perl script, not a shell script.  Question should have indicated that you were willing to take a script of any type.

Comment: @David: you can't get a perfect question when you don't know what's possible. It's your job as the answerer to figure that out. You should think about the intent rather than the literal question.

Comment: @brain d foy : You suggested to use the system( (.... for perl oneliners in code which works really great but can i give ARGV in that oneliner and give the variables in command line while running the code???? If we can then can you suggest me how i can do it???? I have posted a question on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, yes. You take the actual commands and put them in a file. So, using the example from the previous answer, create a file containing:

```
print reverse <>
```

Then run it using perl. On Unix-like machines that would be

```
perl file.pl
```

On windows I guess it will be similar. Search for "running perl scripts under windows", or similar, in google.

Comment: But what u have suggested isnt a oneliner i guess... @terdon

Comment: @unkaitha by definition, a file containing multiple oneliners is NOT a oneliner. If you want to run multiple one liners you just need to extract the code between the 'single quotes' and paste that into a file.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, that wouldn't work and it wouldn't make much sense.  Typically, a perl oneliner calls perl with some commands and parameters.  For example, here's a typical [oneliner](http://www.math.harvard.edu/computing/perl/oneliners.txt):

```
perl -e 'print reverse <>' foo.txt
```

However, if you put this in a script, you get the following:

```
Bareword found where operator expected at .\one.pl line 1, near "'print reverse <>' foo"
        (Missing operator before foo?)
syntax error at .\one.pl line 1, near "perl -e "
Execution of .\one.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

So, the format of script and the format of a oneliner are not compatible.  However, it's usually possible to convert oneliners to script format by extracting the commands and parameters from the oneliner.

Comment: ya just now found that the oneliners can be converted into the perl scripts and then can be added together. But wanted to know if it can be done as described in the question. thank you for the answer @David